# Present UIImagePickerController (or any view controller) from UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Ok so I'm trying to present a view controller from a `UIView` like this:

```
CSCamera *camera = [CSCamera cameraFromYamlNode:answer forView:view];
[view addSubview:camera.view];
```

Now my `CSCamera` view is basically a view controller that does some custom managing of `UIImagePickerController` (custom overlays and things). In order to do this I have a method `showCamera()` that is called to modally present the picker after I add camera.view as a subview:

```
[camera showCamera];
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x1eda8d90>  on <CSCamera: 0x2008e4d0> which is already presenting (null)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: We are going to need to see more of this class. I think the error is telling you that you are trying to present the view twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a big structural problem.

```
CSCamera *camera = [CSCamera cameraFromYamlNode:answer forView:view];
[view addSubview:camera.view];
```

Adding a subview that belongs to a different view controller is unsupported. I think it's the root cause of all your woes.